# Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null or undefined

Tags: reactjs

Expecting the below code to attach an unordered list and its child `<"li" />` nodes to the document.body, it's OK with the `<"ul" />` but without any children and with an error message in the console:

```
React.createElement: type should not be null or undefined. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).
```

(React.js ver.0.13)

```
var ListView = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var items = this.props.data.map(function(item) {
            return ItemDelegate({key:item.id, data:item.id});
        }.bind(this));
        return (React.createElement('ul', null, items));
    }
});

var ItemDelegate = React.createFactory(ListViewChildren);

var ListViewChildren = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (React.createElement('li', {key: this.props.key, data: this.props.data}));
    }
});

var Wrapper = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (React.createElement(ListView, {data: [/*some data*/]}));
    }
});

React.render(React.createElement(Wrapper), document.body);
```

What **type** is it and where is it that the stated **type** has to be declared? I guess there's a total misunderstanding of the concept somewhere, but where?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The warning comes from

```
var ItemDelegate = React.createFactory(ListViewChildren);
```

`ListViewChildren` is defined below so React cannot create the factory.

Just move the `var ListViewChildren = ...` above and the warning will go away.

You also have an issue in the `ListView` class: your `items` should be children and not props:

```
// items as props (2nd arg): won't work, html elements don't have props :)
return (React.createElement('ul', items));
// items as children (3rd arg) should work better
return (React.createElement('ul', null, items));
```

Full code: http://jsfiddle.net/Lmb7t9pv/2/

Comment: I didn't realize it myself at first, but the main reason module loaders are important for react is because they manage module dependencies. So you don't have to remember what depends on what. They ensure that  you don't try and use something that's not defined yet!

Comment: In my case, the element wasn't being properly imported.

Comment: @al8anp I'm struggling with this right now, is there a way for React to actually _tell you_ which component its complaining about?! It leaves it for guess work!

Comment: @JMac Don't suppose you ever found that out? I just wasted a good half hour wondering what was breaking!

Comment: @MattLacey no unfortunately! though this was a little while ago. I think I just slowly eliminated chunks of the code base until I could find it. Now I think I've gotten better at incremental code addition and I can gut find the component that is breaking things.

Comment: @JMac Delete and conquer.